Getting only borders when publishing sheets with graphs to the web of Google Sheets
I had a sheet with 3 graphs that it was published to the web and working fine.
One day i wanted to make some space inside the sheet and move around the graphs.
The graphs looked fine when moved . I placed everything the i way wanted and everything looked ok.
I puplished the sheet to the web and went to see the published sheet and i show only the borders of the graphs exept one that worked ok.
From that time on i can see the graphs inside google sheets that looks fine and when published i see only the borders of them.
Anyone know how to fix that?
this is what i see before publish inside google sheets
and this is the puplished page of the same sheet
I try refreshing page, i try to stop the sheet from going public and republish it to the web ,i try opening the sheet with google chrome , edge,firefox,opera , all in normal mode and in private mode (icognito),i try delete the graphs and remake them  and nothing happend . On all browsers i show only the borders of the graphs exept one.

This is a known issue highlighted by quite a few at docs community forum & has been escalated to google
